# Parameterized constructor on hibernate entity

Tags: java, json, hibernate

**TL;DR**

Is there any way to cleanly pass some arguments to a hibernate-instantiated object post-load?

**What I have**

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Lob
    private String mapAsJson;

    @Transient
    private Map<Long, Double> map = new HashMap<>();

    // Getters, null-checks, and all that. Always keeping these two in sync, or at least before it persists
}
```

**What I want**

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Embedded
    private MyEmbedded<Long, Double> embeddedMap = new MyEmbedded<>();
}

@Embeddable
public class MyEmbedded<K, V> {
    @Lob
    private String mapAsJson;
    @Transient
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

    @PreUpdate @PrePersist
    private void storeAsJson() {
        // JsonUtil encapsulates com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper logic
        mapAsJson = JsonUtil.toString(map);
    }

    @PostLoad
    private void loadFromJson() {
        map.clear();
        if (mapAsJson != null) 
            // JsonUtil encapsulates com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper logic
            map.putAll(JsonUtil.fromString(mapAsJson, HashMap.class));
    }
}
```

**Why do I want it**

Just to nicely encapsulate the hydration to/from this working map object. If I were to have 2 more other fields like this, it would be a lot of repeated code. This is a very specific example, of course, but it could be extended to other objects other than map.

**Why it doesn't work**

This `JsonUtil.fromString(mapAsJson, HashMap.class)` is basically guessing the types. It currently returns a map of `<String, Integer>`, but I'm actually needing `Double`.

**Possible *failed* solution #1**

This of course does not work because hibernate has no idea what my parameters for the embedded object are.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Embedded
    private MyEmbedded<Long, Double> embeddedMap = new MyEmbedded<>(Long.class, Double.class);
}

@Embeddable
public class MyEmbedded<K, V> {
    @NotNull
    private Class<K> keyClass;
    @NotNull
    private Class<V> valClass;

    protected MyEmbedded() {

    }

    public MyEmbedded(Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valClass) {
        this.keyClass = keyClass;
        this.valClass = valClass;
    }

    // [...]

    @PostLoad
    private void loadFromJson() {
        map.clear();
        if (mapAsJson != null)
            // NOTICE THIS DIFFERENT LINE
            map.putAll(JsonUtil.fromString(mapAsJson, HashMap.class, keyClass, valClass));
    }
}
```

**Possible solution #2**

```
@Embeddable
public class MyEmbedded<K, V> {
    @NotNull
    private Class<K> keyClass;
    @NotNull
    private Class<V> valClass;

    // [...]

    // Call this in the entity once, on the embedded. Maybe on @PostLoad?
    public MyEmbedded<K, V> init(Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valClass) {
        this.keyClass = keyClass;
        this.valClass = valClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact class is `JsonUtil`? - Which library are you using. Your variant 'What I want' should work, if the right map is used (Map<String, Object>), though, you'd have to validate that all entries are in fact `Double`s.

Comment: @TreffnonX `JsonUtil` just delegates to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`, with just a few checks and exception handling on top. Validation isn't going to be a problem at the moment, as I know at compile time what I want to put in and get out. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you are using an own `JsonUtil` class to parse `mapAsJson` to an actual Map? then that method needs to be generic. I will post a full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Due to you further specifying that `JsonUtil` is an own class, I would suggest the following signature for `JsonUtil.fromString`:

```java
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> fromString(String json, Class<K> keyClass,
        Class<V> valueClass, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class<? extends Map> mapClass) {
// ...
```

This way, your returned map will be inferred with the correct types, and you can use your 'What I want'-variant. You can have differnent named signatures for other, less bulky access, that delegates to that method:

```java
public static <V> Map<V> fromStringLongKey(String json,
        Class<V> valueClass, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class<? extends Map> mapClass) {
    return fromString(json, Long.class, valueClass, mapClass);
}
//...
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but my question is more of a hibernate one. I need an elegant way to tell my `Embedded` object what are the key and value classes. Only then can I apply your suggestions.